# HTML5 Canvas key event blocks mouse event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouseevent, keyevent

I have this little code. It's the beginnig of a drawing app: https://jsfiddle.net/t2xycjcd/1/ (building on code by www.williammalone.com)

This is the key listener:

```
canvas.onkeypress = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var letter = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); 
    if (keyMap[letter]) {
        settings[keyMap[letter].param] = keyMap[letter].value;
        refreshToolStatusDisplay();
        redraw();
    }
}
```

This is the mouse listener (nothing fancy):

```
canvas.onmousedown = function(e)
    {
        console.log("mousedown");
        clickX = offsetX(e, canvas);
...
```

I am getting crazy about mouse events not correctly firing when happening short time (or immediately) after a key event.

How to reproduce:

1. use the line tool to draw a line
2. press the "p" key to select "player" tool
3. now without pausing and without moving the mouse -> click

The mousedown event will not fire.

It *will* however if you either wait about one second before step three, or move the mouse or click one more time.

This is kind of catastrophic for my purpose.

I have tried various things but none worked:

1. Resetting the focus to the canvas element after the key event -> not the problem, the canvas still has the focus
2. Firing a custom mouse event after the key event through a MouseEvent.initMouseEvent() -> not working
3. Other crazy stuff not worth mentioning

This seems to be typical behaviour of canvas elements. This is a
    similar but unrelated fiddle of a canvas element with a mouse listener: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lanc/ -> Same behaviour there: clicking shortly after a key press will prevent the click from happening.

Anybody have an idea?